# Laplacian equation on non-compact manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete non-compact manifold with bounded geometry, such that the Sobolev embeddings hold.

For the equation 
$$\Delta u=f,$$
for some $f\in L^2(M)$.

**Q** How can we find a solution $u\in L^2$ satisfies the above equation?

Comment: In general you can't. In Euclidean space you can use Fourier analysis to arrive at $\hat u(\xi)=-\hat f(\xi)/|\xi|^2$, which can fail to be square-integrable. Do you have any further conditions?